# Edit sublimetext auto completion?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to edit sublime auto complete snippets(?)? When I want to create php tags I type `<p` and then it suggests the php tag. But if I press enter now it will output `<<?php ?>` so is there a way to edit this so that it simply outputs `<?php ?>` ?

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/weird-double-when-using-auto-complete/20218

Comment: @KeithHall Wasn't that what I said?